# Number split up based on given ranges in Sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a number range 1 -10. I need to split this number based on the given range.
Available data like

```
NumberStart      NumberEnd   Count 
1                     10      10
```

Split the range based on the input set,

```
NumberStart     NumberEnd 
2                3 
5                7
```

So expected result set should like,

```
 NumberStart         NumberEnd     Count
  1                       1         1
  2                       3         2
  4                       4         1
  5                       7         3 
  8                       10        3
```

Could you someone suggest how to achieve this is in SQL query?

Comment: what you have try for this?

Comment: I think you may be missing some data from your examples above. Also, can you please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with Ranges as
    (
        select  1   as  NumberStart,
                10  as  NumberEnd
    ),
    InputSet as 
    (
        select  2   as  NumberStart,
                3   as  NumberEnd
        union all
        select  5,
                7
    ),
    cte as
    (
        select  (select min(NumberStart) from Ranges)   as  rn,
                (select max(NumberEnd) from Ranges)     as  rn_end
        union all
        select  rn+1,
                t.rn_end
        from    cte t
        where   t.rn < t.rn_end
    )
select  min(isnull(t2.NumberStart,t1.rn))                                   as  NumberStart,
        coalesce(t2.NumberEnd,v3.NumberEnd-1,v4.NumberEnd)                  as  NumberEnd,
        count(*)                                                            as  Cnt
from    cte t1
left join InputSet t2 on t1.rn between t2.NumberStart and t2.NumberEnd
outer apply (
                select  min(NumberStart)    as  NumberEnd
                from    InputSet tt
                where   tt.NumberStart > t1.rn
            ) v3
outer apply (
                select  max(NumberEnd)  as  NumberEnd
                from    Ranges
            ) v4
group by coalesce(t2.NumberEnd,v3.NumberEnd-1,v4.NumberEnd)
order by 1
option (maxrecursion 32000)
```

**But!** It doesn't work if intervals set incorrect: you have to guarantee that intervals (`InputSet`) don't intersect and Start is less than End.

Answer (score 0):

I view this as a `union all`.  You want to get the following groups:

- The first group before any rows in `t2`.
- The last group after any rows in `t2`.
- The rows in `t2`.
- The groups "between" rows in `t2`.

This results in a query like this:

```
select t1.numberStart, t2.min_numberstart - 1 as numberend, t2.min_numberstart - t1.numberstart as count
from t1 cross join
     (select min(numberstart) as min_numberstart from t2) t2
where t2.min_numberstart >= t1.numberstart
union all
select t2.max_numberstart + 1, t1.numberend, t1.numberend - t2.max_numberstart as count
from t1 cross join
     (select max(numberend) as max_numberstart from t2) t2
where t1.numberend >= t2.max_numberstart
union all
select t2.numberstart, t2.numberend, t2.numberend - t2.numberstart + 1
from t2
union all
select t2.numberend + 1, tt2.next_numberStart - 1, tt2.next_numberStart - t2.numberend - 1
from t2 cross apply
     (select min(tt2.numberStart) as next_numberStart
      from t2 tt2
      where tt2.numberStart > t2.numberStart
     ) tt2
where tt2.next_numberStart >= t2.numberend + 1
order by numberStart;
```

The only "trick" here is using `cross apply` to emulate the `lag()` function.  `lag()` is available in all *supported* versions of SQL Server, but is not available in SQL Server 2008.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7c4a700c8ae7de07bec429e4e5b16fd0) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of ways to do a number list.  Why not just select your ranges, then union your numbers and left join to the range values?

```
declare @RangeValues table
(
NumberStart int,
NumberEnd int
)
insert into @RangeValues 
values (2, 3), (5, 7), (8, 10)

select NumberStart, NumberEnd, NumberEnd - NumberStart + 1 AS Count
from @RangeValues

UNION

select N AS NumberStart, N AS NumberEnd, 1 AS Count
from dbo.MyNumberListFunction(10) NumberList
  left join @RangeValues V ON NumberList.N >= V.NumberStart 
    and NumberList.N <= V.NumberEnd
where V.NumberStart is null
```

I'm assuming you are missing a range 8-10 above.  Does this get you near your objective?